# TelNet received data varies on each read

Tags: c#, telnet, stringbuilder

I have got a small project to do which involves taking in input from a TelNet client and depending on the input do some processing and return information to the client.

I have got most things working now, a listener in a thread and each client that the listener receives is then given it's own thread. This works fine without any errors. The problems occur when a client has some text input into it and the receiving of this text inside my code, what I receive on a key-press by key-press basis is correct, but when I come to store it in the state object, I get some strange results.

This is the class that is created when the listener receives a new client connection, it is also used with communication to and from the TelNet client:

```
internal class TelNetClient
{
    Socket _socket;

    public TelNetClient(Socket socket)
    {
        var t = new Thread(() => RealStart(socket));            
        t.Start();
    }

    private void RealStart(Socket socket) 
    {
        this.ClientSocket = socket;
    }

    public Socket ClientSocket
    {
        set
        {
            StateObject stateObject;
            DeviceConnection deviceConnection = new DeviceConnection();

            _socket = value;

            stateObject = new StateObject();
            stateObject.WorkSocket = _socket;

            Send(_socket, "Welcome");

            _socket.BeginReceive(stateObject.Buffer, 0, StateObject.BufferSize, 0, 
                new AsyncCallback(ReadCallBack), stateObject);
        }
    }

    internal void ReadCallBack(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
    {
        string content = string.Empty;
        int bytesRead;
        StateObject stateObject;
        DeviceConnection deviceConnection = new DeviceConnection();

        stateObject = (StateObject)asyncResult.AsyncState;

        bytesRead = _socket.EndReceive(asyncResult);

        if (bytesRead > 0)
        {
            ASCIIEncoding ascii = new ASCIIEncoding();
            stateObject.StringBuilder.Append(ascii.GetString(stateObject.Buffer,
                 0, bytesRead));
            content = stateObject.StringBuilder.ToString();

            if (content.EndsWith(deviceConnection.BarcodeTerminator))
            {
                Send(_socket, Environment.NewLine + ">>>>>" + content + "<");
            }
            else
            {
                _socket.BeginReceive(stateObject.Buffer, 0, StateObject.BufferSize, 0,
                    new AsyncCallback(ReadCallBack), stateObject);
            }
        }
    }

    internal void Send(Socket socket, string data)
    {
        Byte[] byteData;

        byteData = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data);

        socket.BeginSend(byteData, 0, byteData.Length, 0, 
            new AsyncCallback(SendCallBack), socket);
    }

    internal void SendCallBack(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
    {
        int bytesSent;
        Socket socket;

        StateObject stateObject;
        stateObject = new StateObject();
        stateObject.WorkSocket = _socket;

        socket = (Socket)asyncResult.AsyncState;

        bytesSent = socket.EndSend(asyncResult);

        _socket.BeginReceive(stateObject.Buffer, 0, StateObject.BufferSize, 0, 
            new AsyncCallback(ReadCallBack), stateObject);
    }
```

The `StateObject` object is as follows:

```
internal class StateObject
{
    internal const int BufferSize = 1024;

    internal Socket WorkSocket = null;
    internal Byte[] Buffer = new Byte[BufferSize];
    internal StringBuilder StringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
}
```

Most of this probably isn't required, but I am showing it all so people can see the full picture.

The issue lies in the `ReadCallBack` method, as you can see I read the byte array and decode it to a string that will then be appended to a `StringBuilder` in the `StateObject` class. The decoded value is correct every time, however when calling `stateObject.StringBuilder.ToString()`, the output is not correct, but it is 100% predictable. Here is an example:

```
Key Press Count | Input from TelNet Client | StrinBuilder.ToString() Output      
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
        1       |             A            |                A
        2       |             B            |                B
        3       |             C            |                AC
        4       |             D            |                BD
        5       |             E            |                ACE
        6       |             F            |                BDF
```

As you can see the final character is always correct, but the preceding characters should be the previous input concatenated together, as you would expect from a `StringBuilder`. This happens 100% of the time throughout all my various tests. It is almost like the `StringBuilder` looses the even/odd characters, but then finds them again the next iteration!

I have tried changing the `StringBuilder` to just a `string`, but the same issue occurs.

Does anyone have any idea why this is happening and how to fix it?

Comment: At a guess, it looks like you might have two `StateObject` instances, and each instance receives every other character. Can't quite follow your code, but you *are* creating a `StateObject` in `set_ClientSocket`, and another one in `SendCallback`, and both of them end up passed to `ReadCallback` as part of two separate `BeginReceive` calls.

Comment: @pmcoltrane You were right, nothing to do with the `StringBuilder`, just the two `StateObject` objects I was working with! Serves me right for not reading through the example code closely enough. You can change your comment to an answer if you want as it is the correct answer for the problem. Thanks.

Comment: I'm glad that helped. I've reposted my comment as an answer and rephrased it slightly.

Comment: As a general advice you should consider using the synchronous socket APIs. They are much simpler. All those callbacks complicate matters to the point where you have trouble spotting issues.

Comment: @usr To be honest, the TelNet part of the program was from another developers prototype and they have tested it with the real devices so I know it works. While I would like to try a simpler way, I know very little about TelNet, so I don't want to do extra work for it not to work when I can finally test it with the real devices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are creating two instances of `StateObject`: one in `set_ClientSocket`, and another one in `SendCallback`. Both of them end up passed to `ReadCallback` as part of two separate `BeginReceive` calls. It looks like each instance is receiving every other character.